# Installing Windows Server 2008R2 in HeadlessVirtualbox in Debian

Tags: virtualbox, debian, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008

I have created a new Headless virtualbox in a Debian Server that should contain a Windows2008R2 server for testing purposes. I followed all the steps [here](https://viaforensics.com/computer-forensics/howto-setup-headless-virtualbox-ubuntu-1004.html)  and the VM seems to run.

All I need now, is to somehow access this VM from my Windows workstation in order to procceed with the setup of the Windows Server. In the [VirtualBox docs](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html#vrde) it says I can use my Remote Desktop application to connect to the VM, but the program gives me an "Invalid Connection file (MY_HOST_IP:3390) specified" error. I'm assuming that's because the Remote Desktop is not enabled yet since no windows are installed yet to that VM.

Is there another way to procceed with the installation?

VirtualBox version: 4.2.22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the HeadlessVirtualbox is a remote desktop server itself. All I had to do, was add an extra flag when run the Remote Desktop client

Entering `mstsc /v:MY_HOST_IP:3390` in the windows command prompt did the trick for me